# Putting variables in regex objects and differentiating them from regular text

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm working on a program that replaces the strip() method, and while this isn't the first time someone mentioned this program on Stack Overflow, I failed to find answers to my specific questions about it on the given thread(s). For reference and context, here's the code :

```
import re

respecchar = ['?', '*', '+', '{', '}', '.', '\\', '^', '$', '[', ']']


def regexstrip(string, _strip):
    if _strip == '' or _strip == ' ':
        _strip = r'\s'
    elif _strip in respecchar:
        _strip = r'\+' + _strip
    re_strip = re.compile('^'+_strip+'*(.+?)'+_strip+'*$')
    mstring = re_strip.search(string)
    stripped = mstring.group(1)
    print(stripped)
```

There are two problems that come to mind in this program :

1. When the _strip argument is in respecchar, it just doesn't work. I tried making the line
   '_strip = r'+_strip' as well as '_strip = rf'+{strip}' and it keeps giving me an error message which I wasn't able to fix no matter what I did. The error was 're.error: multiple repeat at position 4'. When typing the line as '+_strip', the error was 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group''
2. When I type ''GG' and 'G' as the two arguments when I call the function, it doesn't give me an empty string as expected, but a single 'G' for some reason. I know this is a pretty specific situation, but is there any way I could retain this function's other, well, functions, but also making it do the aforementioned task the way I imagined ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something but why are you prepending `\+` in the case of a character from `respecchar`? Shouldn't it just be a `'\'`? Furthermore, the `+` in the capturing group in `re_strip` forces to have at least one character in the group, which explains the `'GG' -> 'G'` issue.

Comment: How does it force at least one character ? Pluses are there solely for concatenation.

Comment: Within a regex expression, `+` has the same meaning as `*` with the difference of requiring at least one match. This means: `re.match(r'.+', '')` is not a match, while `re.match(r'.*', '')` is one.

Comment: But the pluses aren't within the string.

Comment: `re_strip = re.compile('^'+_strip+'*(.+?)'+_strip+'*$')` One of them is. But I see you solved the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The first problem is resolved by using the `escape` function to escape special characters. The second, by changing the group in the regex from `(.+?)` to `(.*?)`, so that the group can be the empty string.

```
def regexstrip(string, _strip):
    if _strip == '' or _strip == ' ':
        _strip = r'\s'
    else:
        _strip = re.escape(_strip)
    regex = '^'+_strip+'*(.*?)'+_strip+'*$'
    re_strip = re.compile(regex)
    mstring = re_strip.search(string)
    stripped = mstring.group(1)
    print(stripped)
```

Comment: I have another question though, about the first problem. I tried typing '*G**' and '*' as the two arguments and the returned string reads 'G**'. Why ?

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, it's the right behavior. You entered "G*" (a G, and then an asterisk), and nothing (which is equal to space) as the char to strip. And - it didn't strip anything. Doesn't that make sense?

Comment: The second argument was an asterisk though. It was omitted when I typed the last comment, I don't know why.

Comment: Nevertheless, I added a question mark after (.* followed by ) and it works properly. I don't have a clue how the '?' thing functions in this case ( non-greedy matching, but I don't entirely get it ) but I guess the most import thing is that it works ?

Comment: When I'm calling regexstrip("G*", "*"), I get a 'G" in response.

Comment: I don't, I only get it when I have (.*?) instead of (.*)

Comment: Right - and that's what I have in my code. It should be non-greedy.

Comment: I don't understand the principle under which the non-greedy segments of the string work, but you aren't willing to elaborate so it's fine, it works either way. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Ah - sorry - I am willing to elaborate. here's the idea: (1) a typical regex is greedy. Meaning, it'll consume as much text as it can. (2) therefore, the regex .* (dot-asterisk) which comes within the parenthesis in your expression will "eat" as much as it can - all the way to the end of the string. (3) by making it non-greedy, you make it "leave" the very end of the string for stripping.

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: It does, but does the greedy version really COMPLETELY ignore everything that comes after, just because it would technically be enough to match the string ?

Comment: The answer, in short, is yes. Think of the following regex, which is comprised of two dot-asterisk groups: (.*)(.*). We'll try matching it to the text 12345. Which group will match which part of the text? With greedy regex, the first group will match as much as it can (the entire string), and leave nothing to the second group.

Comment: See this link, for example: https://blog.finxter.com/python-regex-greedy-vs-non-greedy-quantifiers/#:~:text=So%20the%20difference%20between%20the,the%20quantified%20pattern%20as%20possible. (there are others that explain this as well)